# how to implement google two factor authentication on xamarin form application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-2fa

I have a xamarin form app that needs to implement 2fa.

on the login page, I call the send email and send the code by email to the user.

```
 public async Task SendSecurityCode(string provider) 
        {
            SendSecurityCodeModel model = new SendSecurityCodeModel() { SelectedProvider = provider,     
           
                await _accountAppService.SendSecurityCode(model);
          }
```

then when I got the code by user I can't get true through Api call!
ViewModel:

```
  public async Task VerifySecurityCode(string provider,string code)
        {
            VerifySecurityCodeModel model = new VerifySecurityCodeModel() { Provider = provider,password= Password, tenancyName = _applicationContext.CurrentTenant.TenancyName, usernameOrEmailAddress = _userName, Code = code,UserId = _userId,TenantId = _applicationContext.CurrentTenant.TenantId };
           
                var result = await _accountAppService.VerifySecurityCode(model);
               
        }
```

Appservice:

```
  [UnitOfWork]
        public async Task<bool> VerifySecurityCode(VerifySecurityCodeModel model)
        {
            using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SetTenantId(model.TenantId))
            {


                var loginResult = await _logInManager.LoginAsync(model.usernameOrEmailAddress, model.password, model.tenancyName);
              
                var signInResult = await _signInManager.SignInOrTwoFactorAsync(loginResult, false);


                try
                {
                    var user = await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw new UserFriendlyException(L("  var user = await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();"));
                }
                var result = await _signInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync(
                         model.Provider,
                         model.Code,
                         model.RememberMe = true,
                         model.RememberBrowser = true
                     );

                return result.Succeeded;
            }
        }
```

when I call VerifySecurityCode, it always return false, but if call it by postman it return true only if I set bearer token for authorization tab.

so the issue when I call it through app and it returns false is it doesn't send the token because it is not logged in yet!
I don't know what is the solution!
please help me, it's while I can't resolve it.

Comment: No body can help me?